# json error while parsing using python

Tags: python, json

I am getting a random error while trying to parse a json using python.
here is the JSON string Im trying to parse

```
   {
    "buy_quantity": 456, 
    "tradeable": True,
    "ohlc": {
      "open": 269.9, 
      "close": 269.55, 
      "high": 271.6, 
      "low": 261.5
    }, 
    "average_price": 267.43, 
    "sell_quantity": 0, 
    "last_quantity": 45, 
    "last_price": 268.35, 
    "change": -0.44518642181413043, 
    "mode": "quote",
    "depth": {}, 
    "instrument_token": 784129, 
    "volume": 8224509
    }
```

using JSONLint I tried to see where the error was I get the following response

```
           Error: Parse error on line 3:
           ... 456, "tradeable": True,  "ohlc": {       "
           ---------------^
           Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', 
           got 'undefined'
```

I always get the error on the word tradeable. I dont understand what is wrong here

Comment: `"tradeable": True` jsonlint doesn't unerstand `True` as boolean, it expect a string.  for jsonlint `"tradeable": "True"` while your json is correct for python.

Comment: `True` is Python bool expression, use lowercase `true` in json.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay `json.loads('{"buy_quantity": 456, "tradeable": True}')` throws an Exception as well, it should be `json.loads('{"buy_quantity": 456, "tradeable": true}')`

Comment: using json.loads(data) on the value gives above gives me an error on the word tradeable too as  Expecting value: line 1 column 40 (char 39)

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `treadable` is boolean, it should be : `true`
if it's a string then you need to wrap True in double quotes:

```
 "tradeable": "True",
```

Comment: I would like to explicitly point out that it is `true` with a lowercase and not `True` with a capital to be used as a boolean for json.